# Spring WebFlux security with MongoDb as UserDetails store

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-security, spring-webflux

O I've been setting up security for reactive API where users can log in with username/password to get JWT token, and then use that for everything else. User details (username, password, etc, etc) are stored in MongoDb.

I simply add filter to web filter chain:

`.addFilterAt(buildUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)`

When building this filter, I give it my custom `ApplicationUserService`:

```
    private AuthenticationWebFilter buildUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter() {
        UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager authManager;
        AuthenticationWebFilter usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

        authManager = new UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager(applicationUserService);
        authManager.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);

        usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter = new AuthenticationWebFilter(authManager);
        usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.setRequiresAuthenticationMatcher(ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers(loginPathMatcher));
        return usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
    }
```

This is what `ApplicationUserService` looks like:

```
@Service
public class ApplicationUserService implements ReactiveUserDetailsService {

    private final ReactiveUsersService reactiveUsersService;

    @Autowired
    public ApplicationUserService(ReactiveUsersService reactiveUsersService) {
        this.reactiveUsersService = reactiveUsersService;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<UserDetails> findByUsername(String username) {
        return reactiveUsersService.getUserByUsername(username).cast(UserDetails.class).log();
    }
}
```

This uses `ReactiveUsersService` to fetch users:

```
@Service
public class ReactiveUsersService {

    ReactiveUsersRepository repository;

    public ReactiveUsersService(ReactiveUsersRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public Flux<User> getUsers(){
        return repository.findAll().switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new IllegalStateException("no users"))
        );
    }

    public Mono<User> getUserByUsername(String username){
        return repository.findByUsername(username);
    }
}
```

And finally, `ReactiveUsersRepository`:

```
@Repository
public interface ReactiveUsersRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<User, Integer> {

    Mono<User> findByUsername(String username);
}
```

With this set up I get no errors, but log in does not work. **I just get 401 back**. Note, i have `.log()` added to where I fetch user. This is what it logs:

```
2020-05-06 17:23:54.741  INFO 23348 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] reactor.Mono.MapFuseable.1               : | onSubscribe([Fuseable] FluxMapFuseable.MapFuseableSubscriber)
2020-05-06 17:23:54.742  INFO 23348 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] reactor.Mono.MapFuseable.1               : | request(unbounded)
2020-05-06 17:23:54.743  INFO 23348 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] reactor.Mono.MapFuseable.1               : | onContextUpdate(Context2{interface org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange=org.springframework.web.server.adapter.DefaultServerWebExchange@750265e1, interface org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext=MonoFlatMap})
2020-05-06 17:23:54.743  INFO 23348 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] reactor.Mono.MapFuseable.1               : | onContextUpdate(Context2{interface org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange=org.springframework.web.server.adapter.DefaultServerWebExchange@750265e1, interface org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext=MonoFlatMap})
2020-05-06 17:23:54.744  INFO 23348 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] reactor.Mono.MapFuseable.1               : | onContextUpdate(Context2{interface org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange=org.springframework.web.server.adapter.DefaultServerWebExchange@750265e1, interface org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext=MonoFlatMap})
2020-05-06 17:23:54.825  INFO 23348 --- [ntLoopGroup-2-2] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:3, serverValue:104}] to localhost:27017
2020-05-06 17:23:54.844  INFO 23348 --- [ntLoopGroup-2-2] reactor.Mono.MapFuseable.1               : | onNext(User{id='5eb10474d388c2b64f709b4c', username='admin', email='admin@admin.com', password='$2a$10$qj83J33wn7l9IpNvAlAFQ.fDxaQGwl5Pw4nHRho.Y2wWs1goJny5e', roles=null})
2020-05-06 17:23:54.854  INFO 23348 --- [ntLoopGroup-2-2] reactor.Mono.MapFuseable.1               : | cancel()
2020-05-06 17:23:54.854  INFO 23348 --- [ntLoopGroup-2-2] reactor.Mono.MapFuseable.1               : | onContextUpdate(Context2{interface org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange=org.springframework.web.server.adapter.DefaultServerWebExchange@750265e1, interface org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext=MonoFlatMap})
2020-05-06 17:23:54.855  INFO 23348 --- [ntLoopGroup-2-2] reactor.Mono.MapFuseable.1               : | onComplete()
```

Before, I plugged in MongoDb in `ApplicationUserService` I was using `InMemoryUsersService` where I had a couple of hardcoded users instead of 'ReactiveUsersSercvce' and everythign worked just fine. Essentially i just changed this line to get users from Mongo instead of memory:

```
return reactiveUsersService.getUserByUsername(username).cast(UserDetails.class).log();
```

It seems that it DID fetch the user from Mongo, but failed to authenticate it.
It gives me no errors or anything and I'm new to this reactive spring. 
I'm struggling to debug this and get anything to grasp on.

Comment: According to your log user has been retrived from Mongo,  hence you need investigate code where you compare credentials to auth and from db

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/soasada/kotlin-coroutines-webflux-security explain how to do it (in kotlin but is the same for java)